# Lipo error while converting ARC

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to convert ios old project(which does not contain ARC) to ARC
i got following error

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/xyziPhone-11-03-15/xyz.build/Objects-normal/i386/xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the answer of above question 
Following are the steps to resolve the problem:
1.Go to your project target file 
2.Build setting
3.Set DEBUG flag  **YES** to **" BUILD ACTIVE ARCHITECTURE ONLY "**